# What is the best way to maintain and make secure session? Code I use at the moment

Tags: php, security, web

Session start after auth:

```
session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("location: main.php");
```

And then on every page i use:

```
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

How to improve security over all question. Also how to improve it without SSL

Comment: What security issue are you facing?

Comment: Looking for better option i guess. I know session time is a good add but not sure what i should look further more. Or this type of session is safe? I am new total new guy in this so looking for minds and suggestions over all

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can do many things like:

1. IP based sessions.
2. Allowing a user only one session at any time.
3. Sending notification to user if new system / IP is used to access the interface.
4. Encrypting your data.
5. Sanitizing / validating your inputs with various filters.
6. Using only POST methods in form submissions.
7. For additional security you can opt for storing session information in database rather than files.
8. Timing out sessions in a specified time of inactivity like 24 hours and logging out user automatically.
9. You can use form tokens to accept genuine user information.